# expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token

Tags: c++, cmake

I seem to have a strange problem:

I coded an application in C++ (using Eclipse CDT) that uses Mozilla's Netword Security Services. This application is running fine, so I thought I can just move the appropriate classes/headers/sources to another project (can this generally be done?). The original project uses some additional headers located in `/usr/include/nspr` and `libnss3`.

This other project is compiled using CMake. So I told CMake to add `/usr/include/nspr` to the include path and to use `libnss3`. However, when I try using the classes within this other project, I get the following error when compiling:

```
In file included from some-dir/src/import/FirefoxImporter.h:21:0,
                 from some-dir/src/import/Import_Firefox.h:26,
                 from some-dir/src/mainwindow.cpp:28:
/usr/include/nss/secmodt.h:85:25: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
```

Line 85 in `secmodt.h` looks as follows:

```
PK11SlotInfo **slots;   /* array of slot points attached to this mod*/
```

And `PK11SlotInfo` is typedef'd in `secmodt.h`:

```
typedef struct PK11SlotInfoStr PK11SlotInfo; /* defined in secmodti.h */
```

However, I was not able to locate `secmodti.h` on my system (however, the original program compiled and executed just fine).

Has anybody experienced similar problems and solved them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i suspect you have included QT before secmodt.h. 'slots' is a QT moc keyword.

**Update**

i guessed this because QT is a popular library (and i knew of its usage of `slots`). plus, this type of error looked like typical preprocessor nonsense.

QT's `#define`d 'slots' to nothing for use with its Meta Object Compiler.

you can either: (possibly?) include QT at some point after `secmodt.h`, *or* (possibly?) [add `no_keywords` to your config](http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2/qt4/signalsandslots.html#3rd-party-signals-and-slots) -- then pray to the compiler gods.